PowerShell: Diagnose timeout vs. connection refused on TCP port with Test-NetConnection
I frequently need to diagnose network connectivity issues and I'm currently using Test-NetConnection in PowerShell (Version 5.1). The output tells me if a port is reachable. In case it's not, I would like to know the specific error, e.g. timeout or connection refused. So far, I couldn't find this piece of information in the output.
Is it possible to get the specific error message for a failed connection attempt using Test-NetConnection? If so, how?
For reference, here are three examples of output that I get.

Successful connection

Test-NetConnection somehostname -Port 1433 -InformationLevel Detailed

ComputerName            : somehostname
RemoteAddress           : 10.0.1.201
RemotePort              : 1433
NameResolutionResults   : 10.0.1.201
MatchingIPsecRules      :
NetworkIsolationContext : Private Network
InterfaceAlias          : Dialog
SourceAddress           : 10.0.2.150
NetRoute (NextHop)      : 10.0.2.99
TcpTestSucceeded        : True


Same test from a different source with firewall in between

Test-NetConnection somehostname -Port 1433 -InformationLevel Detailed
WARNING: TCP connect to (10.0.1.201 : 1433) failed

ComputerName            : somehostname
RemoteAddress           : 10.0.1.201
RemotePort              : 1433
NameResolutionResults   : 10.0.1.201
MatchingIPsecRules      :
NetworkIsolationContext : Private Network
IsAdmin                 : False
InterfaceAlias          : Dialog
SourceAddress           : 10.0.2.38
NetRoute (NextHop)      : 10.0.2.35
PingSucceeded           : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT)  : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded        : False


Test closed port on localhost

Test-NetConnection localhost -Port 12345 -InformationLevel Detailed
WARNING: TCP connect to (127.0.0.1 : 12345) failed
WARNING: TCP connect to (::1 : 12345) failed


ComputerName            : localhost
RemoteAddress           : 127.0.0.1
RemotePort              : 12345
NameResolutionResults   : 127.0.0.1
                          ::1
MatchingIPsecRules      :
NetworkIsolationContext : Loopback
InterfaceAlias          : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
SourceAddress           : 127.0.0.1
NetRoute (NextHop)      : 0.0.0.0
PingSucceeded           : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT)  : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded        : False


would this approach be something to look into: try{$(New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient –Argument "www.google.com","444" -ErrorAction Stop).connected}catch{$_.Exception.Message}
